# How do I replace certain parts of an expression

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

Let's say I have this expression

```
2w E^(I w a/ (v+c)) + 4 w^2 E^(I w a / (v-c))
```

I'd like to replace every instance of `E^(something)` with `(1 + something)` without doing

```
/. E^(something) -> 1+something
```

for every single exponential (in reality I have tons of them, not just two).

Is that possible?

Comment: Of course, this is called [**patterns**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html) in Mathematica. Take a look at them, they are at the core of the language. And for your case, use `/. E^something_ :> 1 + something`, or more briefly `/. E^x_ :> 1 + x`

Answer (score 3):

```
expr = 2 w E^(I w a/(v + c)) + 4 w^2 E^(I w a/(v - c));

p = Position[expr, E^x_]
```

{{1, 2}, {2, 2}}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[expr, x_ :> 1 + x[[2]], p]
```

[image]

or, alternatively,

```
MapAt[1 + #[[2]] &, expr, p]
```

(* same result *)